# Is this a valid unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

(I know plural of Person is People, I just like Persons more..)

I am trying to understand the essence of testing. I have a toy project and in this toy project I have the following class:

```
package biz.tugay.jpaExamples.dao;

import biz.tugay.jpaExamples.model.Person;
import biz.tugay.jpaExamples.service.EntityManagerService;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public final class PersonDaoImpl {

    private EntityManagerService entityManagerService;

    public List<Person> getAll() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerService.entityManager();
        final TypedQuery<Person> selectAllPersons = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class);
        final List<Person> persons = selectAllPersons.getResultList();
        entityManager.close();
        return persons;
    }

    public void setEntityManagerService(final EntityManagerService entityManagerService) {
        this.entityManagerService = entityManagerService;
    }
}
```

This method works just fine when I run my project. I inject an `EntityManagerService` to it, and when I call `getAll()` in `PersonDaoImpl`, I will get the `Persons` from the database. This is the implementation I have for `EntityManagerService`, which is not relevant to the question I believe:

```
package biz.tugay.jpaExamples.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public final class EntityManagerServiceByPersistenceUnitNameImpl implements EntityManagerService {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public EntityManagerServiceByPersistenceUnitNameImpl(final String persistenceUnitName) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutDown() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

So because I am trying to study / understand unit testing, I wanted to create a unit test for `PersonDaoImpl`. Here it is:

```
package biz.tugay.jpaExamples.dao;

import biz.tugay.jpaExamples.model.Person;
import biz.tugay.jpaExamples.service.EntityManagerService;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonDaoImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private final PersonDaoImpl personDao = new PersonDaoImpl();

    @Mock
    private EntityManagerService entityManagerService;

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Mock
    private TypedQuery<Person> typedQuery;

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() throws Exception {
        // Given we have 1 person in the database..
        final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        final Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstname("Koray");
        person.setLastname("Tugay");
        persons.add(person);

        // Given entityManagerService returns a valid EntityManager
        Mockito.when(entityManagerService.entityManager()).thenReturn(entityManager);

        // Given entityManager creates a valid TypedQuery
        Mockito.when(entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class)).thenReturn(typedQuery);

        // Given typedQuery returns the persons from the database when getResultList is called
        Mockito.when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(persons);

        // When personDao.getAll is called..
        final List<Person> all = personDao.getAll();

        // Then the returned List must be of size 1.
        Assert.assertTrue(all.size() == 1);

        // And the person in the List returned from the typedQuery must be equal to the person in the initial List.
        final Person returnedPerson = all.get(0);
        Assert.assertTrue(returnedPerson.getFirstname().equals("Koray"));
        Assert.assertTrue(returnedPerson.getLastname().equals("Tugay"));
        Mockito.verify(entityManager).close();
    }
}
```

Is this a valid unit test? If not, is it because I have bad design in `PersonDaoImpl` class, and how do I unit test this method properly?

If it is, can you clarify what it is really testing and how it helps me refactoring or making me confident that I am doing the right thing / I am doing what I am doing right?

Because currently, I see absolutely no benefit in writing this test, but I am pretty sure this is my fault so I am trying to understand.

Comment: The plural of person IS persons. People was accepted as plural after its wide usage in literature. In legal documents and such, "persons" is still used.

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly Thank you. I like "persons" more anyway.

Comment: I think this would be better if it was some other flavor of test. I think this should be a medium sized test with a dummy DB. Because you really want to test if your class can actually interact with the DB.

Comment: Technically, yes. But it just basically tests that the lines of code in the method are the ones expected by the test. The essence of this method is the query itself, and the test doesn't check that this query works as expected. You could replace the query by "hello world" in the test and in the code, and the test would still pass, although, in production, that won't work at all. I'd rather make it a real test, by populating the database with well-known data, then executing the method, then checking that it returns the expected persons.

Comment: In addition to what @JB Nizet said, your test is very strongly tied to the specific implementation. There are multiple ways to write a query that returns the list of all persons, you could for instance change the alias used, in which case the test would (wrongly) fail. For classes whose primary function is to interact with a 3rd party library, integration tests are usually a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer will not be about your test, but about the benefit of a unit test (which is the most important part of your question).

You can't see a benefit writting your test because the benefit grows with time, day after day.

For example : Took a piece of code that you wrote ten years ago. Refactor it, use another lib, upgrade the language to java 8 and use lambdas now, etc... How do you want to know if it's still working now ? By launching the program and testing manually all features ? Even if the project has some millions lines of codes and thousands features ? Nope, you can't. The only way to be sure, is to verify that the previous tests, written when you knew how it should work, still passed.

The test you write today is the proof it works like expected today, but most important, it is the proof it works every time a modification on the implementation is done. Even more when the change is done by another programmer.

Now, to reply to your specific case : in an unit test, don't be focus on testing the implementation (never do that) but focus on the behaviour : what should be the result or the state of your program when your method is called with specific parameters. 
For example here you can setup your test by populating the source with some users and test that the method `getAll()` returns expected data. And another test can verify that the method returns empty list (and not null) when there is not any user.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is a valid unit test. In practice, it is useless.

If you had followed TDD, you would have **written the integration tests first**. With those test running and passing, you would have noticed that all the code of this unit was adequately covered. So you would not have written that useless test.

Had there been a bit more internal logic, an integration test might not have efficiently and adequately exercised it, and a unit test would have been useful.

Defaulting to writing unit tests first is likely the biggest common misconception on how to test. To be more specific, the system/integration/unit distinction doesn't really exist in TDD, instead there are acceptance and developer tests, where:

- acceptance tests are visible to the customer
- developer tests are there to help the developer create software that passes the acceptance tests

Of those developer tests:

- Some developer tests apply to a naturally isolated unit; one with no dependencies.
- Some use an artificially isolated one; using mocks to replace dependencies.
- Some use a unit and it's dependencies, replying on prior testing and accepting a (usually trivial) hit of of slowdown and complexity in finding the underlying fault.

But what you very rarely would do is double up up developer testing, testing the same unit twice, once in isolation and once with dependencies. Doing so is unlikely to help the goal of getting the acceptance tests to pass.

Comment: "If you had followed TDD, you would have written the integration tests first." Do you have reference for this? IMHO this is a highly controversial topic and there's no catch-all solution as it depends on many different aspects.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The funny thing is that [Fowler himself recommends](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html) the [TDD chapter of James Shore's Art of Agile Development](http://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/test_driven_development.html) as "a good place to start [TDD]". Shore says that one "can use TDD for that code [integration tests], too"… as I said, I think the whole topic is ambivalent. And defaulting to integration testing may be the same mistake as defaulting to unit testing.

Comment: Yeah, there would't be some many people getting it wrong if it wasn't such a popular mistake, even trapping some authors. I've added some more detail to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the TDD/XP insights—didn't know myself.